# Unity. Как повернуть часть костной конструкции через скрипт?

Tags: unity3d

[image]

[image]stack.imgur.com/NNcs2.jpg

Нужно что бы при нажатии кнопки объект повернулся. Именно повернулся а не вращался, то есть чтобы при вводе значения -180 объект вернулся в исходное положение.
Где бы не искал везде показывают как вращать объект а не поворачивать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Суть проблемы: всё работало нормально, объект поворачивался вот только мгновенно возвращался в обратную позиция потому что был частью анимации.

Ответ: _object.transform.localEulerAngles = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);